# Deleted posts still show up in search results (sometimes)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, search, deleted-posts

[This deleted Mathematics question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173439/distribution-of-square-of-first-coefficient-of-random-normal-unit-vector) still appears in the search results if you look for its content, e.g. when [searching for "it seems they forgot to take the square root in the denominator"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22it+seems+they+forgot+to+take+the+square+root+in+the+denominator%22):

[image]

[SEDE says](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1071622/deleted-question) it has been deleted on April 4th, so it can't really be a [caching issue](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

The same problem occurs for [this question on Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/would-a-framework-like-the-qa-here-on-stackexchange-allow-the-review-process-of); it can be found when [searching for "This question is about a particular part in the process of scientific publishing"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+question+is+about+a+particular+part+in+the+process+of+scientific+publishing%22). [SEDE says](https://data.stackexchange.com/opensource/query/1078235) it has been asked and deleted on June 6th.

Since then, I found a couple of instances on Stack Overflow:

- [Exhibit 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Building+a+client+using+axis+%28or+similar%29+would+be+the+way+to+go%22) (solved already)
- [Exhibit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22In+Chimp%2C+this+constructor+already+exists%2C+creating+a+world+loaded+with+utility.%22)
- [Exhibit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+searched+about+but+can%27t+find+a+definitive+answer.%22)
- [Exhibit 3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Thus+you+could+have+your+classes+extend+some+interface%2C+say+Reports%3A%22)
- [Exhibit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Check+the+below+blog%22+%22And+the+code+for+the+same%22)
- [Exhibit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22In+my+activity+I+have+button+on+one+side+like+MasterSlave+layout.%22)
- [Exhibit 6](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+just+creating+an+specification+page+for+phone+in+html+and+css%22)
- [Exhibit 7](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22org.jooq.exception.DetachedException%3A+Cannot+execute+query.+No+Connection+configured.+this+is+my+config%3A%22)
- [Exhibit 8](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22right+here+at+line+406%22)
- [Exhibit 9](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22first+column+and+horizontal+and+vertical+scroll%22)
- [Exhibit 10](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+would+like+to+plot+my+spectrum+only+to+15+Hz%22)
- [Exhibit 11](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22deploy+a+.war+file+to+the+tomcat+server+automatically+using+ANT.%22)
- [Exhibit 12](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+tested+it+so+long+time%21%21%21+Help+me%7E%7E%7EThx%7E%7E%7E%22)
- [Exhibit 13](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+am+working+with+a+python+script+which+create+runs+in+2+threads.%22)
- Other post IDs which can be found with an appropriate search: 48417504, 48446529, 48469104, 48464546, 48473605, 48482922, 48484882, 48489810, 48508784, 48508917, 48510682, 48511172, 48511437, 48515113, 48519100, 48520105, 48521567, 48522293, 48524855, 48524770, 48525033, 48525319, 48525448, 48525527, 48525701, 48525796, 48525851, 48525883, 48527039, 49351664, 52823823

The problem seems to have intensified late 2017 and in January 2018, but then it mostly stopped occurring; only the last two posts are younger.

It seems that undeleting and redeleting the post might solve the issue.

<sub>(Originally posted on [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30421/228959), but I found more instances later.)</sub>

Comment: This is probably also related with the migration of the tag engine to .Net Core. Maybe boolean logic got replaced with [`true; false and file_not_found`](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you suspected, undeleting and re-deleting the question removed it from the index. With the original deletion so far in the past, it's hard to know why it was missed - so for now, the best we can do is fix up the immediate problem.

If you encounter any other instances of this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The Open Data question I mentioned is still visible...

Comment: And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Building+a+client+using+axis+%28or+similar%29+would+be+the+way+to+go%22&mixed=0) another one for you, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Deleting/undeleting works there too. I'll betcha there's a race somewhere...

Comment: and another one: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Check+the+below+blog%22+%22And+the+code+for+the+same%22&mixed=1 (I do know you have more pressing matters at hand - I'll remove the other comments and refer to the list in the question.)